# What is the file path for the Ubuntu Software Centre executable?

Tags: software-center

What is the file path for the Ubuntu Software Centre executable?  usr/bin/ maybe?

Also what is the file name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is handy tool called `whereis`:

> **% whereis software-center**
>
> software-center: /usr/bin/software-center
>   /usr/bin/X11/software-center /usr/share/software-center
>   /usr/share/man/man1/software-center.1.gz

Answer (score 2):

For completions sake.

You can also use the tool `which`.

```
% which software-center

software-center: /usr/bin/software-center /usr/bin/X11/software-center
```

It is slightly better in this perticular use case, since it shows only the executable files

See [which/whereis differences](https://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences) for the difference between the two.